# Map array's file objects data to another array's field respectively

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to add each file to `document_details` array objects respectively. The array is as follows:

```php
"location_description" => "Dolorem cillum aliqu"

"document_details" => "[
  {"id":"new_1582611729993","document_description":""},
  {"id":"new_1582611733087","document_description":""}, 
  {"id":"new_1582611736002","document_description":""}
]"

"files" => array:3 [
  0 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1018
      -test: false
      -originalName: "readme.md"
      -mimeType: "text/markdown"
      -error: 0
      #hashName: null
      path: "/tmp"
      filename: "phpNB2p5w"
      basename: "phpNB2p5w"
      pathname: "/tmp/phpNB2p5w"
      extension: ""
      realPath: "/tmp/phpNB2p5w"
      aTime: 2020-02-25 11:52:19
      mTime: 2020-02-25 11:52:19
      cTime: 2020-02-25 11:52:19
      inode: 917746
      size: 2031
      perms: 0100600
      owner: 1000
      group: 1000
      type: "file"
      writable: true
      readable: true
      executable: false
      file: true
      dir: false
      link: false
    }
    1 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1023.....}
    2 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1023.....}
```

My `vue` code is so far:

```js
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('document_details', JSON.stringify(self.document_details));

this.files.forEach(function (file) {
  formData.append('files[]', file);
});
```

`files` is an array with file objects. I'm working with `vue.js` and a `laravel` project.

Comment: If you wish to send these files to your server, then no, you don't want them there. As you are doing is probably the best, so they are sent as binary, in their own --boundary in the multipart request. You could maybe duplicate their metadata in the JSON part but leave the binary files here.